# Is there a Base64Stream for .NET?

Tags: base64, .net

If I want to produce a Base64-encoded output, how would I do that in .NET?

I know that since .NET 2.0, there is the [ICryptoTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.icryptotransform.aspx) interface, and the 
[ToBase64Transform()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tobase64transform.aspx) and [FromBase64Transform()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.frombase64transform.aspx) implementations of that interface.

But those classes are embedded into the System.Security namespace, and require the use of a TransformBlock, TransformFinalBlock, and so on.

Is there an easier way to base64 encode a stream of data in .NET?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you want a stream that converts to Base64, you can put a `ToBase64Transform` into a [`CryptoStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.cryptostream.aspx):

```
new CryptoStream(stream, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
```

If you just want to convert a single byte array to Base64, you can simply call [`Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx).

In both cases, you can replace the word `To` with `From`.

Comment: Looks easy.  Can you set RFC 2045 line lengths on that stream?

Comment: You can call `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks)`  However, `ToBase64Transform` does not expose that option.

Comment: ok that's odd.  So if I wanna create a base64 doc for MIME-attach  purposes (a la RFC 2045), then I can't used that, but if I convert FROM a base64 doc, it would work?

Answer (score 7):

With the simple answer from **@SLaks** I have written a simple solution:

```
/// <summary>
///     Encodes the specified input stream into the specified output stream.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inputStream">
///     The input stream.
/// </param>
/// <param name="outputStream">
///     The output stream.
/// </param>
/// <param name="lineLength">
///     The length of lines.
/// </param>
/// <param name="dispose">
///     true to release all resources used by the input and output <see cref="Stream"/>;
///     otherwise, false.
/// </param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
///     inputStream or outputStream is null.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
///     inputStream or outputStream is invalid.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="NotSupportedException">
///     inputStream is not readable -or- outputStream is not writable.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="IOException">
///     An I/O error occured, such as the specified file cannot be found.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">
///     Methods were called after the inputStream or outputStream was closed.
/// </exception>
public static void EncodeStream(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, int lineLength = 0, bool dispose = false)
{
    if (inputStream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputStream));
    if (outputStream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outputStream));
    var si = inputStream;
    var so = outputStream;
    try
    {
        int i;
        var cs = new CryptoStream(si, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        var ba = new byte[lineLength < 1 ? 4096 : lineLength];
        var sep = new byte[] { 0xd, 0xa };
        while ((i = cs.Read(ba, 0, ba.Length)) > 0)
        {
            so.Write(ba, 0, i);
            if (lineLength < 1 || i < ba.Length)
                continue;
            so.Write(sep, 0, sep.Length);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dispose)
        {
            si.Dispose();
            so.Dispose();
        }
    }
}

/// <summary>
///     Decodes the specified input stream into the specified output stream.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="inputStream">
///     The input stream.
/// </param>
/// <param name="outputStream">
///     The output stream.
/// </param>
/// <param name="dispose">
///     true to release all resources used by the input and output <see cref="Stream"/>;
///     otherwise, false.
/// </param>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
///     inputStream or outputStream is null.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
///     inputStream or outputStream is invalid.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="NotSupportedException">
///     inputStream is not readable -or- outputStream is not writable.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="IOException">
///     An I/O error occured, such as the specified file cannot be found.
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">
///     Methods were called after the inputStream or outputStream was closed.
/// </exception>
public static void DecodeStream(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, bool dispose = false)
{
    if (inputStream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputStream));
    if (outputStream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outputStream));
    var si = inputStream;
    var so = outputStream;
    try
    {
        var bai = new byte[4096];
        var bao = new byte[bai.Length];
        using (var fbt = new FromBase64Transform())
        {
            int i;
            while ((i = si.Read(bai, 0, bai.Length)) > 0)
            {
                i = fbt.TransformBlock(bai, 0, i, bao, 0);
                so.Write(bao, 0, i);
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (dispose)
        {
            si.Dispose();
            so.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

I only use CryptoStream to encode because I've found it has problems decoding Base64 hahes with line breaks, while FromBase64Transform can do that easily without CryptoStream. I hope the rest is clear enough that I do not have to explain anything.

**Example:**

```
const int lineLength = 76;
const string sourcePath = @"C:\test\file-to-encode.example";
const string encodedPath = @"C:\test\encoded-example.base64";
const string decodedPath = @"C:\test\decoded-base64.example";

// encoding
using(var fsi = new FileStream(sourcePath, FileMode.Open))
    using (var fso = new FileStream(encodedPath, FileMode.Create))
        EncodeStream(fsi, fso, lineLength);

// decoding
using(var fsi = new FileStream(encodedPath, FileMode.Open))
    using (var fso = new FileStream(decodedPath, FileMode.Create))
        DecodeStream(fsi, fso);
```

Comment: You ought to publish it, in a Nuget package. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you are looking for:

http://mews.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/52969#392973

Answer (score 0):

System.Convert provides that, here is a code sample that might help

```
private string EncodeBase64(string toEncode)
{
  byte[] toEncodeAsBytes = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toEncode);
  string returnValue = System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
  return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Useful, but in my case, I don't want to use the ToBase64String.  It's not a stream and is likely to not work very well with large data.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @sombra 's answer, I needed something similar but in a way that was easier to use by my Web API when processing large files which needed to be sent to its S3 storage in a Stream format. This is what I came up with so far

```
/// <summary>
///     Decodes input Base 64 encoded data to the specified <see cref="Stream"/>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="outputStream">
///     Output <see cref="Stream"/>
/// </param>
/// <param name="base64Data">
///     Base 64 encoded data
/// </param>
/// <returns>
///     outputStream length
/// </returns>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
///     outputStream or base64Data were null
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
///     outputStream is invalid
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="NotSupportedException">
///     outputStream isn't writable
/// </exception>
/// <exception cref="ObjectDisposedException">
///     Methods were called to outputStream after it closed
/// </exception>
public static long DecodeBase64Stream(Stream outputStream, string base64Data)
{
    if (outputStream == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(outputStream));
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64Data))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(base64Data));
    }

    const int bufferSize = 80 * 1024;
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[bufferSize];
    byte[] byteOutput = new byte[bufferSize];
    int c = Math.Min(base64Data.Length, bufferSize);

    using FromBase64Transform transform = new();

    while (base64Data[..c].Length > 0)
    {
        int totalBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(base64Data[..c]);

        byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64Data[..c]);
        totalBytes = transform.TransformBlock(byteArray, 0, totalBytes, byteOutput, 0);
        outputStream.Write(byteOutput, 0, totalBytes);
        base64Data = base64Data[c..];

        c = Math.Min(base64Data.Length, bufferSize);
    }

    transform.Dispose();
    return outputStream.Length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like there is a `Base64Stream` class. Maybe it'll help future readers.

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/net/System/Net/mail/Base64Stream.cs

Comment: This does not completely answer the original question: that class is marked **internal** and you can't just copy the source code because it is *for reference* only.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think you can't copy the source.

Answer (score -2):

The CryptoStream does not do RFC2045 line endings. Therefore that won't work for me.
The ToBase64String is unacceptable because it's not a streaming approach.  I don't want to hold all the data in memory at one time.

Therefore I needed alternatives.

Richard Grimes posted one here:
http://www.grimes.nildram.co.uk/workshops/encodedStream.htm

Rather than use that, because of licensing and feature needs, I wrote an independent implementation, available here:
http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=streams&file=Base64Stream.cs

It is licensed under [the MS-PL](http://opensource.org/licenses/ms-pl.html).

To use this to compress then base64-encode a file, do this:

```
byte[] working= new byte[1024];
int n;
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(fileToCompress))
{
    using (Stream output = new FileStream("file.deflated.b64"))
    {
        using (var b64 = new Base64Stream(output, Base64Stream.Mode.Encode))
        {
            b64.Rfc2045Compliant = true; // OutputLineLength = 76;

            using (var compressor = new DeflateStream(b64, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                while ((n = input.Read(working, 0, working.Length)) != 0)
                {
                    compressor.Write(working, 0, n);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need a custom stream class; you can just use a `CryptoStream`.  See my answer.

Comment: yes, but I couldn't figure out how to do RFC2045-compliant line lengths with the builtin class.  So I *did* need a custom class, as far as I am aware.

Comment: @Cheeso how Can i decompress the stream outputed from your code snippet?

Comment: Well you'd just run the content through a compressor. But compressing a base64 string produced from compression seems like the wrong idea. The original content is compressed, then it is base64 encoded. Compressing the output would have the result of  removing the benefits of base64 encoding. Also it likely wouldn't have any good result, since the content is already compressed therefore the base64 encoding of said content will be mostly incompressible.

Comment: @Cheeso, I'm interested in taking a look at your Base64Stream, but that winisp.net link appears to be dead. Do you have it anywhere else?

Comment: Dead links. Please don't post links, post the code.