# Not able to determine the format from long data type content

Tags: java

In my old Oracle database's table there is a column of data type long.

I am trying to read the that column's content to a file like below:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class TheMainClass{

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String username = "easyusername";
        String password = "toughpassword";
        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@server.com:1521/theservicename",
                "" + username + "", "" + password + "")) {

            try (PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(
                    "SELECT IMAGECONTENTS_COMPRESSED FROM images_compressed where IMAGE_COMPRESSED_K = 'D25Q0XS9T0'");
                    ResultSet rset2 = s.executeQuery()) {
                if (rset2.next()) {
                    byte[] bytes = rset2.getBytes(1);
                    try {
                        FileOutputStream file = null;
                        file = new FileOutputStream("somefilename.pdf");
                        file.write(bytes);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        String err = e.toString();
                        System.out.println(err);
                    } finally {
                        System.out.println("All Done. !");
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The file is written successfully but I can't open it as a PDF. When I open it with some text processor app like notepad++ it shows content as two lines.

First line is - "FORMAT-ZIPV2" and

Second line is a super long string :

```
FORMAT-ZIPV2
504B0304140002000800AC7D113702F7FE42B1340000574900000E000000643235713078733974302E706466EDBC775853CDF6284CEFCD8222520216108524404882F45EA42ANDAVERYLONGSTRING
```

Any idea what kind of format it is AND how do I write correctly to a file ? Please let me know if any other details are needed. I can provide them as update.

I tried the following to remove FORMAT-ZIPV2 and tried to decode using Base64 but still the resultant zip file still throws error for not being a valid zip file:

```
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("zipfilename.pdf")));
            String newContent = content.replaceAll("FORMAT-ZIPV2", "").replaceAll("\\r|\\n", "");
            System.out.println("File Content:: " + content);
            System.out.println("File New Content:: " + newContent);
            Base64.Decoder dec = Base64.getDecoder();
            String decoded = new String(dec.decode(newContent));
            System.out.println("decoded value is \t\n\n" + decoded);
            Path path = Paths.get("somezipfilename.zip");
            try {
                Files.writeString(path, decoded, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.print("Invalid Path");
            }
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/5678666/1509264 (summary, strip the first 13 characters, i.e. the `FORMAT-ZIPV2` and the new line, and then write the remaining bytes to a Zip file)

Comment: I'd use `getBinaryStream().transferTo` Unclear file type so far. Save a small one we can examine

Comment: @g00se can you please provide a sample/pseudo code?

Comment: There is code in the linked duplicate.