# Encode a FileStream to base64 with c#

Tags: c#, string, file, base64, filestream

I know how to encode / decode a simple string to / from **base64**.

But how would I do that if the data is already been written to a **FileStream** object. Let's say I have only access to the FileStream object not to the previously stored original data in it. How would I encode a **FileStream to base64** before I flush the FileStream to a file.

Ofc I could just open my file and encode / decode it after I have written the FileStream to the file, but I would like to do this all in one single step without doing two file operations one after another. The file could be larger and it would also take double time to load, encode and save it again after it was just saved a short time before.

Maybe someone of you knows a better solution? Can I convert the FileStream to a string, encode the string and then convert the string back to a FileStream for example or what would I do and how would such a code look like?

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but it's possible to use built-in classes to provide a stream which will transform binary data to or from base 64 data. You could then interpose such a stream between your writes and a file output stream (such as is commonly done with compressing streams and encrypting streams). An example is here: http://netpl.blogspot.co.uk/2011/05/builtin-base64-streaming.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an Stream into a byte\[\] in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-to-convert-an-stream-into-a-byte-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Base64Stream for .NET? where?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525533/is-there-a-base64stream-for-net-where)

Comment: Isn`t [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919641/1042934) the answer?

Comment: Do not forget: stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); at the beginning of method... ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also encode bytes to Base64. How to get this from a stream see here: [How to convert an Stream into a byte[] in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080442/how-to-convert-an-stream-into-a-byte-in-c)

Or I think it should be also possible to use the .ToString() method and encode this.

Comment: Since the input is a stream, a much more useful answer is the one below that transforms the stream to another (B64 encoded) stream.

Answer (score 63):

An easy one as an extension method

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static Stream ConvertToBase64(this Stream stream)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(base64));
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in the `stream` being buffered entirely into memory (with multiple copies too, as you don't set an initial `capacity`). This is not a practical solution for files larger than a few megabytes - and will certainly break for files larger than 2GB (as `MemoryStream` uses a single `Byte[]` internally). People also report `MemoryStream` breaking for sizes over 256MB: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595061/outofmemoryexception-while-populating-memorystream-256mb-allocation-on-16gb-sys

Comment: @Dai I think that if you are trying to base64 encode a stream that is large, maybe there is a better alternative than base64 encoding?  I'm doing it to supply a file within a JSON web request, if there is a large file (MBs+), then it doesn't make sense for me to do that.

Comment: This solution wastes a lot of memory (few times) and cpu time. It can be done much optimal!

Comment: @VasilPopov Please post your optimal solution.

Comment: @PhillipCopley
I did it few posts below

Comment: The value of using a stream is not to have to load all the data in memory. No interest in using a memorystream

Answer (score 56):

When dealing with large streams, like a file sized over 4GB - you don't want to load the file into memory (as a `Byte[]`) because not only is it very slow, but also may cause a crash as even in 64-bit processes a `Byte[]` cannot exceed 2GB (or 4GB with `gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`).

Fortunately there's a neat helper in .NET called `ToBase64Transform` which processes a stream in chunks. For some reason Microsoft put it in `System.Security.Cryptography` and it implements `ICryptoTransform` (for use with `CryptoStream`), but disregard that ("a rose by any other name...") just because you aren't performing any cryptographic tasks.

You use it with `CryptoStream` like so:

```cs
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.IO;

//

using( FileStream   inputFile    = new FileStream( @"C:\VeryLargeFile.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 1024 * 1024, useAsync: true ) ) // When using `useAsync: true` you get better performance with buffers much larger than the default 4096 bytes.
using( CryptoStream base64Stream = new CryptoStream( inputFile, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Read ) )
using( FileStream   outputFile   = new FileStream( @"C:\VeryLargeBase64File.txt", FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 1024 * 1024, useAsync: true ) )
{
    await base64Stream.CopyToAsync( outputFile ).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Note that the leaveOpen property is invalid in netstandard2.0, but is accepted in 472

Comment: This is almost perfect, except the resultant stream doesn't support Seek, which I need. I swear every day I work with C# System lib I find something I need to re-implement properly.

Comment: @YarekT If you're using streams then you should never need to seek (the only exception being `FileStream`). If you find yourself needing to seek in a non-disk stream then your system is likely designed wrong.

Comment: @Dai Interesting. I'm using `FluentFtp`'s `UploadAsync` method which takes a stream. I assumed it wouldn't seek, but it does. I'm guessing they designed it for regular file streams.

Comment: @YarekT According to this issue, it's because FluentFTP needs to know the length of a stream beforehand (which is reasonable), however it does that by requiring streams be seekable (which is wrong - but a consequence of the design of `System.IO.Stream` which doesn't let it expose a `Length` unless `CanSeek == true`, grrr): https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP/issues/668

Answer (score 15):

A simple Stream extension method would do the job:

```
public static class StreamExtensions
{
    public static string ConvertToBase64(this Stream stream)
    {
        if (stream is MemoryStream memoryStream)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }

        var bytes = new Byte[(int)stream.Length];

        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        stream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)stream.Length);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

The methods for Read (and also Write) and optimized for the respective class (whether is file stream, memory stream, etc.) and will do the work for you. For simple task like this, there is no need of readers, and etc.

The only drawback is that the stream is copied into byte array, but that is how the conversion to base64 via Convert.ToBase64String works unfortunately.

Comment: This is not a generic solution as many many stream types will not support Length or Seek()

Comment: Rhys Bevilaqua, Usually you would need to either seek to the beginning of the stream to read it all, or to "know" that you are in the beginning (which is against SOLID principles).
ONly streaming does not implement these 2 methods - almost all the rest (memory, file, etc) have it. You can always have second implementation where you read buffer by buffer until the "end" of the stream, but this is not so efficient and straightforward.

Comment: I'm sick of buffering everything to byte[] in .NET. It's tremendously wasteful. It's high time for stream APIs end-to-end.

Comment: Updated a bit to support the ToArray() method of the MemoryStream class.

Answer (score 13):

You may try something **like** that:

```
    public Stream ConvertToBase64(Stream stream)
    {
        Byte[] inArray = new Byte[(int)stream.Length];
        Char[] outArray = new Char[(int)(stream.Length * 1.34)];
        stream.Read(inArray, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        Convert.ToBase64CharArray(inArray, 0, inArray.Length, outArray, 0);
        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(outArray));
    }
```

Comment: Where does 1.34 come from?

Comment: A byte holds 8 bits. A base64 doesn't use bytes but chars. Not any chars, but specific chars that can be converted to 6 bits. So the in-array is smaller than the our-array by a factor 6/8. 8 divided by 6 is 1,33333 so if you take 1.34 the out array will always be just big enough.

Comment: You need to get the new size from `Convert.ToBase64CharArray` and then do `Array.Resize<Char>(ref base64Chars, newSize);`. Otherwise, you have extra bytes in the final output.

Comment: The 1.34 is wrong! The extra 0.0333 gives you some space which is too small for small lengths and unnecessary big for big arrays. Instead of flooring (cast to int) you should do a ceiling `(int)Math.Ceiling(stream.Length * 8.0 / 6.0)` so you get the exact length.

Comment: Note that if `stream` happens to be a `MemoryStream`, you can just use [`stream.ToArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream.toarray?view=netframework-4.7.2) and avoid the 8/6 calculations.

Answer (score 7):

The answers recommending the use of `ToBase64Transform` are valid, but there is a big catch. Not sure if this should be an answer, but had I known this it would have saved me a lot of time.

The problem I ran into with `ToBase64Transform` is that it is hard-coded to read 3 bytes at a time. If each write to the input stream specified in `CryptoStream` constructor is something like a websocket or anything that has non trivial overhead or latency, this can be a huge problem.

Bottom line - if you are doing something like this:

```
using var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(httpRequestBodyStream, new ToBase64Transform(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
```

It may be worthwhile to fork the class `ToBase64Transform` to modify the hard-coded 3/4 byte values to something substantially larger so that it incurs fewer writes. In my case, with the default 3/4 value, transmission rate was about 100 KB/s. Changing to 768/1024 (same ratio) worked and transmission rate was about 50-100 MB/s because of way fewer writes.

```
    public class BiggerBlockSizeToBase64Transform : ICryptoTransform
    {
        // converting to Base64 takes 3 bytes input and generates 4 bytes output
        public int InputBlockSize => 768;
        public int OutputBlockSize => 1024;
        public bool CanTransformMultipleBlocks => false;
        public virtual bool CanReuseTransform => true;

        public int TransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount, byte[] outputBuffer, int outputOffset)
        {
            ValidateTransformBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount);

            // For now, only convert 3 bytes to 4
            byte[] tempBytes = ConvertToBase64(inputBuffer, inputOffset, 768);

            Buffer.BlockCopy(tempBytes, 0, outputBuffer, outputOffset, tempBytes.Length);
            return tempBytes.Length;
        }

        public byte[] TransformFinalBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
        {
            ValidateTransformBlock(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount);

            // Convert.ToBase64CharArray already does padding, so all we have to check is that
            // the inputCount wasn't 0
            if (inputCount == 0)
            {
                return Array.Empty<byte>();
            }

            // Again, for now only a block at a time
            return ConvertToBase64(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount);
        }

        private byte[] ConvertToBase64(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
        {
            char[] temp = new char[1024];
            Convert.ToBase64CharArray(inputBuffer, inputOffset, inputCount, temp, 0);
            byte[] tempBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(temp);
            if (tempBytes.Length != 1024)
                throw new Exception();

            return tempBytes;
        }

        private static void ValidateTransformBlock(byte[] inputBuffer, int inputOffset, int inputCount)
        {
            if (inputBuffer == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(inputBuffer));
        }

        // Must implement IDisposable, but in this case there's nothing to do.

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Clear();
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) { }

        ~BiggerBlockSizeToBase64Transform()
        {
            // A finalizer is not necessary here, however since we shipped a finalizer that called
            // Dispose(false) in desktop v2.0, we need to keep it in case any existing code had subclassed
            // this transform and expects to have a base class finalizer call its dispose method.
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the file will be larger, you don't have very much choice in how to do this. You cannot process the file in place since that will destroy the information you need to use. You have two options that I can see:

1. Read in the entire file, base64 encode, re-write the encoded data.
2. Read the file in smaller pieces, encoding as you go along. Encode to a temporary file in the same directory. When you are finished, delete the original file, and rename the temporary file.

Of course, the whole point of streams is to avoid this sort of scenario. Instead of creating the content and stuffing it into a file stream, stuff it into a memory stream. Then encode that and only then save to disk.