# Client Side converting File to Base64 and then to StreamContent in order to upload file to an API as MIME

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a client that uploads a file to an API (see code):

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
   using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
   {
      // THIS LINE SHOULD BE CHANGED TO RETURN A Base64 StreamContent object 
      var fileContent = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(txtFileLocation.Text));

      fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
              FileName = Path.GetFileName(@"C:\text.mp4")

      content.Add(fileContent);

      var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:1234/api/upload", content).Result;
    }
}
```

The API expects a MIME base64 file.

I'm familiar with how to encode a file into a string base64. What I don't know is: how can I pass this string as a MIME File Upload to the API?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134062/encode-a-filestream-to-base64-with-c-sharp

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with encoding a file, what I don't know is how to then pass it to the API File Upload so that it still arrives as MIME and can be decoded on the server.