# binding base64 image to image tag jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I am returning a file result in base64 format:

```
string stream = this.userManagementRepository.getphotbytes(photoIdUrl);
return this.File(stream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet,"file.png");
```

I am binding it like this:

```
$("#photoIdStreamImg_" + userid).attr("src", Result);
```

The image not visible at all. Please help with this issue.

Comment: Assuming `Result` is the Base64 string, then use `attr('src', 'data:image/png;base64,' + Result)`

Comment: Could you post the value of `Result`

Comment: I dont think you are returning a base64 there... I think you are returning a file as a  stream instead. Try encoding the stream to base64, it should work then

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you are returning base64 there.
Base64 is a simple string.

Try using the `Convert` namespace, and use

```
Convert.ToBase64String
```

Look up for more info [here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134062/encode-a-filestream-to-base64-with-c-sharp)