# Why is WPD Datagrid Usercontrol bound to row datacontext not updating?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, user-controls

I have a DataGrid bound via a ListCollectionView to an ObservableCollection of Objects with type Job, say. Each cell in the DataGrid contains a UserControl which has a dependency property named Job which is bound to the DataGridRow.DataContext (using Mode=TwoWay). Everything displays correctly.

The problem is that I have a background process which mutates objects referenced by the Job object and those get displayed by the UserControl. Obviously, Job does not change so the view does not change.
How can I get the user controls in each cell to update themselves with the new data?

Answer (score 0):

With lists there are 3 kinds of ChangeNotification you have to take care of:

- the one for each property of the Job Class.
- the one if elements are added or removed from the collection. That is the only part ObservableCollection takes care off.
- the one on the property exposing the list/CollectionView/whatever. ObservableCollection lacks a AddRange function so on large operations (like a rebuild of the list) it would spam the UI with changes. The solution is to build a new list in the background, then expose it in this property.

One particular issue might be the Background Process too, if it is Multi**threading**. GUI's are [protected against being written from the wrong Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14703806/3346583). But threads are also notoriously good at swallowing Exceptions. Usually you need to write a faulty Catch, but they do it for free. As a result, your might run int oa CrossThread exception and never notice it.

For a better answer, we need some actuall code. Like teh job class, the BackgroundProcess, etc.

Comment: The background thread uses Dispatcher.BeginInvoke to update the UI data objects. I think the problem is that the user control has only the Job binding and this does not change. I am going to try to add another property to the Job object called revision number and bind this to a new Dependency property on the user control. The updater can then increase the revision number which should trigger a property change in the user control which can then update itself. I will re-post here when I have a result.

Comment: @PeterWilson What about the 3 forms of binding? Why do you not show us code? And did I read it right that you used DependencyProperties for your ViewModel?

Comment: The technique I outlined above works. However, we have hit multiple problems with the background updater: 1. Massive Server hit, 2. Stupifying memory leak, 3. SQL deadlocks. We have decided to go back to a simple refresh button.  This also solves the problem as we refresh the whole grid.

Comment: @PeterWilson: For 2, People often missread the memory figures or missunderstand how the GC works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58486473/3346583 | Without showing us the querry we can not really help with it.